# How do you print a valiable found in the class for the loop

Tags: python-3.x

/* what was the pint self.n from **iter** or **next**
I tried str(iter(self.n)) but get NameError: name 'self' is not defined */

```
class PowTwo:
    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max
#
    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 1
        return self
#
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
#
# How do you print self.n in __iter__ or __next__
#
for item in PowTwo(4):
    print("Self.n: " + str(iter(self.n)) + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
p = PowTwo(4)
it = iter(p)
while True:
    try:
        # get the next item
        print(it.n,next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        # if StopIteration is raised, break from loop
        break

#1 2
#2 4
#3 8
#4 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the instance in a variable first:

```
powtow = PowTow(4)
for item in powtow:
    print("Self.n: " + powtow.n + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
```

In Python 3.8, it will be possible to write it with one line less:

```
for item in powtow := PowTow(4):
    print("Self.n: " + powtow.n + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
```

But until then, assignment isn't allowed in expressions.